# Can't set gas limit for oraclize callback function higher than the default 200000

Tags: contract-debugging, oracles

Could you please help me with the following.
I am using OraclizeIt (https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api) to retrieve a JSON  from some other service via REST. Basically the smart contract method in question is simply

`function update(uint24 id) {
        oraclize_query("URL", "json(bla-bla-bla).0.parameters", 200000);
}`

Third parameter (here 200000) is a gas limit for oraclize callback function. And i can't seem to set it higher than 200000 which is its default value. If i attempt to set it to a higher value lets say 250000 i inevitably get an error in the transaction which says **"Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Bad instruction] "**  and nothing else to go on even though i don't really have my own instructions only what Oraclize implements in their contract.I can't use default 200000 either because it's not enough for my callback i need to set the gas limit higher. I used ethereum-bridge(https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-bridge) at first and testRPC then i moved to ropsten. The error persists. Maybe somebody could point me where to look and what might cause this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to send along enough ETH as the first query is free just up to 200k gas: if you need more gas for your callback tx, then the first call to oraclize_query has to be paid for too. On testnets of course this is practically free, but testnet ethers need to be sent anyway! Try to send along some ethers and it will work just fine ;)